# How can I use prompt-sync to get the value of 1 keypress?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, user-input

I am trying to write a command line game in JS that takes user input. I am using prompt-sync module to get user input in node, but I am having trouble figuring out how to limit the user input to one keypress. The code below gives you an idea of the functionality I'm trying to implement:

```
const prompt = require("prompt-sync")();
let playAgain = prompt(`Play again? Enter y to replay, any other character to exit: `);
if (playAgain.toUpperCase === 'Y') {
  runGame();
} else {
  return false;
}
```

I have read [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt-sync) but am relatively new to node and can't find anything that indicates how to end the input before the 'Enter' button is hit. Is there a way to do this? Should I use a different module like Inquirer.js?

Answer (score 0):

You're in the right direction. The function `prompt` returns a `string` which represents the keyboard's key that was pressed.

In order to check if the user's answer was a capital "Y" you'd have to compare `playAgain` (which is a string with the key that was pressed by the user) with  the string `'Y'`.

So you can either compare the string `playAgain` (the user's answer) as-is:

```
if (playAgain === 'Y') {
  runGame()
} else {
  return false
}
```

Or, in case you'd like to accept both lower and upper case (`'y'` or `'Y'`) as valid answers, you'd just have to invoke the `.toUpperCase` method:

```
// like this
if (playAgain.toUpperCase() === 'Y') {
  runGame()
} else {
  return false
}
```